# Products not updating after Magento e-commerce update

Tags: magento-1.9

I keep getting this error after upgrades,

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION'
>   in
>   app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\helper\gallery.phtml
>   on line 111

I have searched for solutions, but not working.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error occur when there is issue `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/image.php`.So if that is the case, there are two possible solutions

Solution 1: Just renamed the image.php file to image.php.bak (located in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper` and this then reverted back to the core file.

Solution 2: copy and paste the file from core and move it to Local

**I hope this will help**